# How do you delete an IoT Device Telemetry Data programmitcally with CSharp in Azure IoT Central or Azure IoT Hub?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-central

I am trying to programmatically delete telemetry data in Azure IoT Central/IoT Hub using CSharp.  Is there any api's to do this without deleting the devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device telemetry data are ingested into the underlying streaming resource such as the Event Hubs and they are stayed there based on the retention policy, see more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#event-retention).

Note, that the events can't be deleted explicitly from the Event Hubs and the shortest possible retention period is 1 day.